# javascript: getting class name from html code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to get class names from an html code using javascript, I can get the class names like this

```
var cPattern = new RegExp(/class[ \t]*=[ \t]*"[^"]+"/g);
var cMatches = data.match(cPattern);
```

but it is giving me results in array having values like

```
['class="hello-world"', 'class="any-name"' , ... ]
```

How to get resulting array with just values

```
["hello-world", "any-name", .. ]
```

Comment: Class values aren't necessarily enclosed in quotes.

Comment: @RobG And even if they are, they're not necessarily double-quotes ^_^ The pony watches closely...

Comment: I guess someone's been sniffing/swallowing/absorbing some secret sauce… ;-)

Comment: I *maaaaay* have slept in the Dark World's Zophan last night... Hehe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cPattern = new RegExp(/class[ \t]*=[ \t]*"[^"]+"/g);
var cMatches = data.match(cPattern).map(function(v){
    return v.split("=")[1].replace(/^['"]|['"]$/g, "");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: No]
<sub>(source: [nooooooooooooooo.com](http://nooooooooooooooo.com/vader.jpg))</sub>

You have a DOM! Right there! You're in JavaScript, the DOM is right there! There! Look, I'm pointing at it! ... You can't see my hand? Okay then...

```
var tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = data;
var elementsWithClassNames = tmp.querySelectorAll("[class]");
var classNames = [], l = elementsWithClassNames.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) classNames[i] = elementsWithClassNames[i].className;

console.log(classNames);
```

Comment: actually its nodejs and I cannot create DOM from html

Comment: Aaaaaand... the [tag:nodejs] tag is... where?

Comment: No nodejs tag but also no html tag ;)

Comment: So you admit to mis-tagging your questions and making me look like an idiot?